# Parse XML element's attributes in SQL query

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

Need to store ECB exchange rates in some tool, where MS SQL server queries are stored, and cannot get info from XML web page.

This is source XML on web with exchange rates
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

These are my experiments: I create XML variable and fill by XML (later XML will be in nvarchar column in a table)

```
DECLARE @RateXML XML
SELECT @RateXML = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2022-02-16">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1372"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="131.56"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>';
```

I tried these, no one works.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as gesmes)
select a.currency.query('Cube/@currency') as currency from @RateXML.nodes('gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube') as a(currency);
--Error: Attribute may not appear outside of an element
    
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as gesmes)
select a.currency.value('Cube/@currency', 'varchar(max)') as currency from @RateXML.nodes('gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube') as a(currency);
-- 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
    
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as gesmes)
select @RateXML.query('gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube/@currency') as currency;
-- Attribute may not appear outside of an element
```

Is there any different simple approach? I would like to select a temporary table with 2 columns, currenty and rate. Thanks for trying ...

Comment: What is your expected result? and why do you use CTE tables (XMLNAMESPACES) in the queries if you never use them?

Comment: Expected result is to get somehow out currencies and rates into table. I have no idea, what are CTE tables, simply I tried everything I could google out.
Lower is the solution by Yitzhak Khabinsky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do correctly.

Both namespaces should be taken care. As @RonenAriely mentioned, you need to declare and **use** namespaces.

> later XML will be in nvarchar column in a table

It is better to use column of XML data type for that.

Benefits:

- XML data type storage is much less than `NVARCHAR(MAX)`
- XML data type has powerful XQuery API to handle any operation for the XML
  data.
- XML data type has special XML indexes for performance. 3 types of indexes.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @RateXML XML =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2022-02-16">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1372"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="131.56"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref'
    , 'http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' AS gesmes)
SELECT c.value('@currency', 'CHAR(3)') AS currency
    , c.value('@rate', 'DECIMAL(10,4)') AS rate
FROM @RateXML.nodes('/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----------+----------+
| currency |   rate   |
+----------+----------+
| USD      |   1.1372 |
| JPY      | 131.5600 |
| BGN      |   1.9558 |
+----------+----------+
```